# Clone object with function

Tags: javascript

I wanted to clone original object and function without reference, is my code consider the correct way to clone object and function?

```
var apple = new function() {
    this.type = "macintosh";
    this.color = "red";
}


function aaa() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
    };

var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(apple))
var b = 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(apple));

console.log(a)


a.getInfo = aaa

b.getInfo = aaa

a.color='green' // only a is green color

console.log(a.getInfo())

console.log(b.getInfo())
```

Comment: At the time of "cloning" your object didn't even contain the function

Comment: Yes, I shown an example which function is not in the object but every questions I found didn't seem to mention how to clone function existed in the object and discard by JSON parse.

Comment: So do you care about the functions now or not? Then adjust your example appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
var clone = function (object) {
  // Copy everything that is not an object
  if (object == null || typeof(object) !== 'object') {
    return object
  }
  // Calling constructor
  var temp = new object.constructor()

  // Recursively cloning children
  for (var key in object) {
    temp[key] = clone(object[key])
  }

  return temp
}
```

Test:

```
var test = { a: 0, b: function () { console.log(1) } }
var cloned = clone(test)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feshcdLe/1/

Comment: Only a is copied b function is not copied?

Comment: @JamesLei did you try it ?

Comment: I tried it, b didn't get copy, only a? Could you have a JSFiddle as I'm on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For cloning objects, you can use `Object.assign` and set the first argument as an empty object.
For example

```
const clone = Object.assign({}, apple.call({}));
const result = aaa.call(clone);
console.log(result);
//=> red macintosh apple;
```

I made use of `Function.call` here simply because I don't know if you meant to access the global `this` or a different scope or what. If you *do* know what your `this` is referring to, then you can simply do.

```
const clone = Object.assign({}, this);
const result = aaa();
console.log(result);
```

[MDN Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

[MDN Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: That's not what MDN says. It copies the values of the original object. It runs getters too. It only references if the original object contains references.

Comment: True, correction, it useful for simple object, I tried to add function into the original object and assign, it didn't get to clone the function to a new object as I like to.

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood the question then. Perhaps this solution provided by the same assign documentation does what you need it to? Look to the `completeAssign` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Copying_accessors

Comment: Almost there, except, I could only use "get bar()" and not "set bar(..)"?

Comment: Did the cloned object have a setter defined for `bar`?

Comment: Havent tried, I found by creating a new constructor can copy both old object and function to a new object correctly, that the easier approach than assign or completeassign